# Rounded corners of MKMapView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm building a custom UITableView with each of the cells containing a piece of text and a MKMapView. I want the map "icon" view in the cell to have rounded corners and this seems to be an issue.

I'm using custom drawing both for my UITableViewCell and my `MapIcon` (custom map view) that I add to my UITableViewCell.

`MapIcon` is a subclass of `MKMapView` and the drawing method looks as follows:

> -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
>
> ```
> CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
> CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeWidth);
> CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,self.strokeColor.CGColor);
> CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.rectColor.CGColor);
>
> CGFloat radius = arcRadius;
>
> CGFloat Xmin = CGRectGetMinX(rect);
> CGFloat Xmid = CGRectGetMidX(rect);
> CGFloat Xmax = CGRectGetMaxX(rect);
>
> CGFloat Ymin = CGRectGetMinY(rect);
> CGFloat Ymid = CGRectGetMidY(rect);
> CGFloat Ymax = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);
> ```
>
> CGContextBeginPath(context);
>       CGContextMoveToPoint(context, Xmin, Ymid);
>       CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, Xmin, Ymin, Xmid, Ymin, radius);
>       CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, Xmax, Ymin, Xmax, Ymid, radius);
>       CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, Xmax, Ymax, Xmid, Ymax, radius);
>       CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, Xmin, Ymax, Xmin, Ymid, radius);
>       CGContextClosePath(context);
>
> ```
> CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
> ```
>
> CGContextClip(context);
>     CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);
>   }

And the maps do not get the corners rouned, as can be seen in the below screenshot:

[alt text http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/948/picture1vmk.png](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/948/picture1vmk.png)

If however I change the `MapIcon` to subclass from UIView and use the same custom drawing methods, the view gets clipped perfectly, image below:

[alt text http://img503.imageshack.us/img503/6269/picture2xkq.png](http://img503.imageshack.us/img503/6269/picture2xkq.png)

Is it wrong for me to subclass MKMapView in such a way and expect it to clip?
Any other any of rounding these corners?

Cheers, 
Kaspa

Comment: Did you find that putting a mapview here crashes when it exits and re-enteres the view?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The easiest way to make round corners:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
myMapView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
```

Comment: Works like charm, thanks!
Time to sit down and read more on CA I guess.

Comment: its cornerRadius, not cornerRadious

Answer (score 3):

Just a small correction as the import statement is misspelt in digdog's answer.

Should be

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
myMapView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the last paragraph of the Overview section in the [MKMapView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html):

> Although you should not subclass the MKMapView class itself,...

I think that pretty well answers your question of whether you should subclass it.  One thing you could do is put another view on top of the MKMapView that looks like the background to round the corners.  If you need it to be of arbitrary size, you can try the `strechableImage` method on `UIImage`.

Comment: That subclassing note is written in the context of getting the information regarding the maps behavior. I should be able to subclass it to mainpulate the UIView (just like digdog has described)

Answer (score 0):

It's also fairly easy to round specific corners if you need. For example, when the map is located at the top of a *NSTableViewCell* inside a grouped *NSTableView*

Slightly modified from [ACEToolKit](https://github.com/acerbetti/ACEToolKit/tree/master/ACEToolKit):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
- (void)awakeFromNib {
CGRect rect = self.bounds;
float radius = 10.f;

// Create the path
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];

// Create the shape layer and set its path
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = rect;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

// Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the view's layer
self.mapView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```